# React js CSS same class name style is used on another page

Tags: reactjs

I used reactjs app, i am use coustom css file. i use css class name for a page , now I have added some styles in that class. now If face some problem, when I add sem  class name in another page , it automatically gets previous that style. I don't want to get any previous style in that class, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

recommend use styled-component or taiwwind etc easier to controll your css.